# How to read contents from TreeSet and Write to file?

Tags: java, data-structures

My Code is:

```
Set<String> s1=new TreeSet<String>();
   s1.add(name);
   s1.add(gender);
   s1.add(dob);
```

How to read these variables and write it to a file? Should i use Buffered Reader and Buffered Writer??

Comment: What have you tried so far? USe FileReader/FileWriter api to read/write to a file in java

Comment: Sounds like you need to go back to the tutorials before you try anything like this.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Answer (score 1):

**Try the Following code**

```
public class SetWriter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String name = "Muhammad", gender = "male", dob = "8/feb/1992";
    Set<String> s1 = new TreeSet<>();
    s1.add(name);
    s1.add(gender);
    s1.add(dob);
    File f = new File("D:\\east.txt");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
    for (String s: s1) {
        fw.write(s+"\r\n");
    }
    fw.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use a BufferedWriter wrapped around a FileWriter. Iterate over the elements of the set and write each element to the BufferedWriter. Make sure you close the writer.

Answer (score -2):

String is serializable so you can simply do it by JXB. Or simpler read this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm
or that http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaSerialization/article.html